# Markov Chain: prove that state is positive recurrent by calculating expected # of transitions to return to this state

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Given the transitional probabilities below (states: 0,1,2,3), I need to prove that state 3 is positive recurrent by calculating expected # of transitions to return to this state

$$P =
\pmatrix{0.65& 0.35 &0 &0\\
0.5& 0.1& 0.4 &0 \\
0.1 &0 &0 &0.9\\
0.6 &0 &0 &0.4\\}$$

now I see the all states communicate and the matrix is finite, then the MC is irreducible
and there is only one class. it also follows that the states are positive recurrent.

however, I need to make the claim about the positive recurrence of state 3 through calculating expected # of transitions to return to this state if starting from state 3.

How would I calculate this? I know there are some formulas for special Markov Chains, but I can't seem to understand the correct approach here. I cannot calculate it as E[..] by conditioning since it becomes infinite recurrence..

Comment: Are your states 0,1,2,3 or 1,2,3,4?

Comment: @Stefanos 0,1,2,3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve the following system of recursive relations. Denote by $h(k)$=the number of transitions to return to state $3$ when starting from state $k$. We want to calculate $h(3)$ and show that $h(3)<\infty$. Assume you start in state 3 as required and you will make a transition. You will either land in state $0$ with probability $0.6$ and start over or you can land in state $3$ with probability $0.4$ and in that case you are done. So the expected number of transitions $h(3)$ is equal to $$h(3)=1+0.6h(0)+0.4\cdot0$$ where $1$ stands for the transition that you already made. Now, we need to calculate $h(0)$. For that end, assume now that you start in state $0$ and you will make a transition. You will either land in state $0$ with probability $0.65$ or you can land in state $1$ with probability $0.35$ and start over. So the expected number of transitions $h(0)$ is equal to $$h(0)=1+0.65h(0)+0.35h(1)$$ Similarly we find the following system $$\begin{cases} h(3)=1+0.6h(0)+0.4\cdot0 \\ h(0)=1+0.65h(0)+0.35h(1) \\h(1)=1+0.5h(0)+0.1h(1)+0.4h(2) \\ h(2)=1+0.1h(0)+0.9h(3)\end{cases}$$ Solving the aboves yields $h(0)=30.1, h(1)=27.2 ,h(2)=21.2 ,h(3)=19$ (Doublecheck please for mistakes in the equations and the calculations, methodology is correct). So $$h(3)=19<\infty$$ and therefore state $3$ is positive recurrent (as is of course any other state due to the properties of communication that you have already mentioned).

Comment: thank you very much! What if this MC had some transition states and some recurrent, how can I show that a state is transitional? In that case probability of ever coming back should be less then one, but how can I calculate it for a relatively small (like 4-7 states) Markov Chain?

Comment: First separate the states in communication classes. Then it will be easy, because from these classes some will be transitional and some recurrent (or absorbing). This way (with the recurrence) is the most computationally demanding. The probability you are asking is again calculated with a similar recursive relation.

Comment: @Stefanos thanks for the well explained solution. But would it be necessary to evaluate h(k) for each state as initial state or would taking one example (X0=3 in your example) suffice?

Comment: @Abhinav No, generally it would not suffice. You have to evaluate it for all k.